# How to use eclipse debugger to debug stacktrace of JSF core libraries?

Tags: eclipse, spring, jsf, remote-debugging

Welcome
I am extending some application written with Sprint and JSF. My work is partly writing xml config files. After some changes I got reports from library generators.

Can I access with Eclipse debugger attached jars and fount what method throws error (and why) ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to rephrase what you are asking for here.

Of course you can attach with the Eclipse debugger to that application. You will need to run it in debug mode though. You will need to pass in some parameters to the JVM. Something like

```
java -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=127.0.0.1 ..
```

You might also want to point Eclipse to the source jars so you can step through the code. But since you are talking about config files I would rather check the logs first.